# Amend results from two collections into an array using _.each()

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, underscore.js

My goal:

Call an API and inside this API I would like to:

1. Find Bills
2. Find all transactions under each bill (by billId)
3. Return the values in a JSON ARRAY

The bill array look like this:

```
{ _id: 549bf0597886c3763e000001,
billName: 'Leasing',
startDate: Thu Dec 25 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET),
endDate: Sun Oct 15 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST),
amount: 16500,
type: 4,
timestamp: Thu Dec 25 2014 12:09:13 GMT+0100 (CET),
__v: 0 },
{ _id: 54a014bfac01ca3526000001,
billName: 'Test',
startDate: Tue Oct 28 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET),
endDate: Wed Dec 20 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET),
amount: 1000,
type: 4,
timestamp: Sun Dec 28 2014 15:33:35 GMT+0100 (CET),
__v: 0 }
```

---

From this array, which I get in the step 1, I would like to query the transactions collections and get each transaction for each bill.
The array would have the following transformation:
From:

```
{ _id: 549bf0597886c3763e000001,
billName: 'Leasing',
startDate: Thu Dec 25 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET),
endDate: Sun Oct 15 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST),
amount: 16500,
type: 4,
timestamp: Thu Dec 25 2014 12:09:13 GMT+0100 (CET),
__v: 0 },
{ _id: 54a014bfac01ca3526000001,
billName: 'Test',
startDate: Tue Oct 28 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET),
endDate: Wed Dec 20 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET),
amount: 1000,
type: 4,
timestamp: Sun Dec 28 2014 15:33:35 GMT+0100 (CET),
__v: 0 }
```

To:

```
{ _id: 549bf0597886c3763e000001,
billName: 'Leasing',
startDate: Thu Dec 25 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET),
endDate: Sun Oct 15 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST),
amount: 16500,
type: 4,
timestamp: Thu Dec 25 2014 12:09:13 GMT+0100 (CET),
__v: 0 ,
transactions: {
  { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("549ea8c957b654ef64000003"), 
    "billId" : "5499aece1d7be6c6a3000001", 
    "paymentDate" : ISODate("2014-12-27T12:40:41.311+0000"), 
    "amount" : NumberInt(2400), 
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-12-27T12:40:41.311+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
  }
  { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("549ea9446163b3c666000001"), 
    "billId" : "5499aece1d7be6c6a3000001", 
    "paymentDate" : ISODate("2014-12-27T12:42:44.975+0000"), 
    "amount" : NumberInt(2400), 
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-12-27T12:42:44.975+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
  }

}
},
{ _id: 54a014bfac01ca3526000001,
billName: 'Test',
startDate: Tue Oct 28 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET),
endDate: Wed Dec 20 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET),
amount: 1000,
type: 4,
timestamp: Sun Dec 28 2014 15:33:35 GMT+0100 (CET),
__v: 0 }
```

In my attempt, Im succeding until I get the bills ID from the bill collection but I cannot succeed to get the transaction IDs into an array.

My attempt looks like this:

```
app.get('/getbills', function(req,res) {

    function getTransactions(item, key){

            var billId = item._id;

             Transactions.find({billId : billId}, function(err, transactions){ // TODO: Needs to look for transactions inside the date.
                if (err)
                    console.log('error: '+ err)
                else if (transactions.length !== 0){
                    return transactions;
                }
            });                

        };

    Bills.find({type: bill_type}).find(function(err, bills){
        if(err)
            res.send(err);

        details.bills = bills;

        details.bills.transations = _.each(bills, getTransactions);

     res.send(details);  
    });

});
```

I'm using `_.each` to hold the billId and query the transactions table but there are not enough examples explaining how to use this function in the way I'm trying. Or maybe my attempt is wrong.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With `_.map`, you can change the array directly, in case you would want to do that.

Comment: @KimGysen Would you be able to give me an example with my case? I have looked into map but I didn't understand very well how I would apply to my case. I have also tried it but the return was weird (something like: `,,` and `,`. Thanks

Comment: Can you make a simple example fiddle? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, a simplified example might be interesting. I'm not using Mongoose, but I might be able to help you with underscore. Just simplify the loop you are looking for to convert with map and I'll have a look. Btw, you didn't add it in your previous comment.

Comment: @KimGysen, basically what I'm trying to do resumes to this [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/dennislaymi/dnvacLaw/2/) . Now, Im pretty sure I should not try to get the value into the variable when the code runs because the value from the _.map is not yet populated (as it is asynchronous). And thats where I'm stucked in the example above. So I need guidance on how to deal with such a situation. Please let me know. Cheers

Comment: If it is asynchronous, you need to wait until the call is finished and then make the loop based on the array parameter that is sent to the callback.

Comment: And how to wait in JS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68144/discussion-between-kim-gysen-and-dennis-laymi).

Answer (score 0):

You are not waiting for you second call to finish, so you don't have all data at hand. Your `return` statement does not work as you think it will.

You should read a bit about asynchronicity in JavaScript :)

This code should work. Please take some time to study it and understand why. The `trySend` function acts as a simple synchronizer and only responds when all data is available. This is not the best way to do it - only the simplest.

```
app.get('/bills', function( req, res ) {
  Bills.find({type: bill_type}, function( err, bills ) {
    if( err ) return res.send(err);

    var tries = 0;
    var details = { bills: bills };
    var trySend = function (){
      tries++;
      if (tries === bills.length) {
        res.send(details);  
      }
    };

    bills.forEach( function ( bill ) {
      Transactions.find({billId : bill._id}, function ( err, transactions ) {
        if ( err ) return res.send( err );

        bill.transations = transactions;
        trySend();
      });  
    });        
  });
});
```